# Magento: adding static attribute to catalog_product, but can't ensure saving values to it

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Since many hours I try to figure out a weird behaviour of Magento with static attributes.

After a while I found a solid way to add a static attribute within a setup script

```
$installer = $this;

$setup = Mage::getModel( 'eav/entity_setup', 'core_setup' );

$installer->startSetup();

// adding the color code attribute as static attribute
$setup->addAttribute( 'catalog_product', 'color_code', array(
    'group'             => 'General',
    'label'             => 'Color Code',
    'note'              => 'the color code',
    'type'              => 'static',
    'input'             => 'text',
    'backend'           => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_default',
    'source'            => '',
    'frontend'          => '',
    'required'          => false,
    'filterable'        => true,
    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL
) );

$installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
    $installer->getTable( 'catalog/product' ),
    'color_code',
    array(
        'type'          => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        'length'        => 64,
        'comment'       => 'Color Code'
    )
);

$installer->endSetup();
```

The first thing I'd to grok: It's necessary to add the column to the entity table by myself... ok did it.
The given script allows me to have the correct input in the admin backend, and if there is a value in the specified column it will appear in the corresponding input field in the admin backend... that's nice :-)

And now... the great mystery :-(

**If I try to save a value to the new attribute it doesn't work.** Well that's not completely correct. At the beginning it doesn't keep the new values. After debugging the whole Magento down to Varien and Zend classes to find the reason it suddenly works, without changing anything in the code. While debugging I often reset my module and removed and readded the attribute and also cleared caches and reindexed the catalog. Now it works perfect, even if the attribute is removed and readded again and again o.O

To understand what happened I tried it with a new attribute `foo`, and the same weird behaviour occurs... after many many debugging, inspecting, coffee... it suddenly works, too.

For all next test cases with the test attributes `bar`, `foobar`, `argh`, `grmph` ... happens exactly the same again and again.

Ok, let's pushed the setup script to another Magento installation, and...?! ... yes, the same o.O

This way I can't ensure my setup script does, what it's meant to :-(

*Info: I need the static attributes to avoid unnecessary joins while finding other product with the same attribute (color code) value. The static attributes a basically available in each collection without adding special attributes to the collection.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got it...

just needed to add

```
$installer->getConnection()->resetDdlCache();
```

at the end of the setup script